# Ubuntu login screen changed to MATE?

Tags: 14.04, mate

We recently restarted a Ubuntu 14.04 (with default desktop) install we are using as a server for git. I think this is quite possibly the first time it has been restarted since January.

When I initially remote'ed into the running machine (before restart) the login screen appeared as the normal default Ubuntu login screen. After the restart we see the ubuntuMATE login screen...what the heck is going on?

Some of the small interface stuff seems to have switch to MATE, e.g selecting icons in a file explorer highlights them in green instead of orange, the system settings > system details page intiially gave an error with a green ubuntu symbol but now just crashes the system settings window... what the flip!?!?

according to `lsb_release -a` the version is 14.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try uninstalling the MATE Desktop environment.

1. Run `sudo apt-get remove --purge mate-*` to remove MATE.
2. Run `sudo apt-get autoremove`.

If something comes up, asking about your default login manager, choose `gdm`.